# Permission screen appears when share a message on facebook from wp8 app

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, facebook-sdk-4.0

I need to share a message on facebook from wp8. I attached my Main.xaml screenshot.

[image: This is view of the Main.xaml]

When click share button, first login to Facebook and then ask permission for the App. I used following code.

```
 private FacebookSession session;
    private async Task Authenticate()
    {
        string message = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            session = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,publish_actions,read_stream");

            App.AccessToken = session.AccessToken;
            App.FacebookId = session.FacebookId;

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Share/LandingPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)));
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            message = "Login failed! Exception details: " + e.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }
}
```

And then in Loading method of LandingPage.xaml , used following code to publish message.

```
    private async void LandingPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("message", "First test post using Facebook login");

        await client.PostTaskAsync("me/feed", parameters);
    }
```

When I run the App , successfully login to the Facebook, but permission screen appear as follows.
[image: screenshot of the permission page]

clicked ok . And then an error is occurred.

```
(OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

I tried to solve this issue my best , but I failed . If anybody has an idea to solve this. please help me

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you are missing the Request code from your access token request.

```
dynamic result = facebookClient.Get("oauth/access_token", new
{
    client_id = appId,
    client_secret = appSecret,
    grant_type = "authorization_code"
    redirect_uri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri,
    code = Request["code"]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I got the access token in Authenticate() method using following code. 
`session = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,publish_actions,read_stream");
App.AccessToken = session.AccessToken; ` Is it not correct ?